# `forkIO` and `putMVar`: what's going on under the hood?

Tags: haskell, concurrency, mutable

I am hoping someone can help me understand why the following code generates the output below.  The code is from the Concurrency chapter in Simon Marlow's book (link below).

Based on the description of the various functions, I assumed that the second `putMVar` function should get blocked given that (i) both `putMVar` functions are part of the same thread and (ii) a value has already been assigned.  Clearly that's not the case.  It would be great to understand what's going on 'under the hood' here.

(Note: the book uses `do` notation but I have a preference for `>>=` notation as I think it's more straightforward - hence the version of the code below.)

[Link to book](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000929/ch07.html#sec_mvars)

```
import Control.Concurrent

main :: IO ()
main = newEmptyMVar >>=
       \m -> forkIO (putMVar m 'x' >>= \_ -> putMVar m 'y') >>=
             \_ -> takeMVar m >>=
                   print >>=
                   \_ -> takeMVar m >>=
                         print
```

Output of the code above:

```
% ./mvar2
'x'
'y'
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For my own sake, here's the code in `do` notation.

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  m <- newEmptyMVar
  forkIO $ do
    putMVar m 'x'
    putMVar m 'y'
  x <- takeMVar m
  print x
  y <- takeMVar m
  print y
```

What we have is a background thread and the main thread running concurrently communicating over a small piece of memory, the `MVar` called `m`.

`MVar` semantics are as such: an `MVar` can be empty or full. If you want to read an `MVar` and it is empty then you must wait until it become full. If you `readMVar` then you will simply resolve the value stored in a full `MVar` as soon as you can. If you `takeMVar` then you will resolve the value and then immediately *empty* it after reading.

On the other side, when you `putMVar` to put a new value into an `MVar` you will succeed immediately if the `MVar` is empty. If it is full then you must wait until it becomes empty.

Since there is waiting on the read and the write sides then the threads become *synchronized* over the emptiness and fullness of the `MVar`.

So in this example, we can imagine many possible linearized stories for how the execution goes forward. Fortunately, they all work identically. Let's call the background thread `BG` and the main thread `MN`.

```
t = 1  :  MN makes a new, empty MVar called 'm'
t = 2  :  BG puts 'x' in 'm' making it full
t = 3  :  BG attempts to put 'y' in 'm', but since 'm' is full BG blocks
t = 4  :  MN attempts to read 'm' and succeeds as it is full
t = 5  :  BG now places 'y' into the newly empty 'm'
t = 6  :  BG dies
t = 6  :  MN prints the value it previously read
t = 7  :  MN attempts to read 'm' and succeeds as it is full
t = 8  :  MN prints the value it previously read
t = 9  :  MN dies
```

As we can see, `BG` is prevented from putting more values in the `MVar` than what `MN` can read. This produces the printed semantics you observed.